# How to get ID while insert data to mysql db?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Below is my table structure, id is primary key and cat_code is unique.

```
--------------------------------------
 id   cat_code  cat_name  created_by
--------------------------------------
```

How can I return id after insert data to database? cmd.LastInsertedId can return id if the record is not duplicate, but when the record is duplicate cmd.LastInsertedId always return 0, how can I get the actual id if the record is duplicate?

```
                Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO main_item_cat(cat_code,cat_name,created_by)" &
                                      "VALUES (@cat_code,@cat_name,@created_by)" &
                                      "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                                       cat_code=@cat_code,
                                       cat_name=@cat_name,
                                       created_by=@created_by"

                Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                    For Each drow As DataRow In dt_main_item_cat.Rows
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat_code", drow(0).Trim())
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat_name", drow(1).Trim())
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created_by", g_currUser)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

                        dt_cat_dtl.Rows.Add(cmd.LastInsertedId, drow(0), drow(1))
                    Next
                End Using
```

Comment: Check if the value is 0, and if it is run a select query to get the item? SQL simply alerts you if there's a duplicate, it doesn't actually return that id